# Second cohomology group of an affine Lie algebra

Tags: representation-theory, lie-algebras, group-cohomology

If $L$ is a finite-dimensional simple Lie algebra (over $\mathbb{C}$), then it is apparently the case that $H^2(L\otimes\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}],\mathbb{C})$ ($L\otimes\mathbb{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ being the loop algebra of $L$, with Lie bracket $[x\otimes f,y\otimes g]=[x,y]\otimes fg$) is isomorphic to $\mathbb{C}$. In the literature that I have looked at I can only find one proof (Conformal Field Theory and Topology - T. Kohno), but this relies on the fact that $L$ is the Lie algebra of a compact Lie group.

My question: is there an algebraic proof, and if so, does someone know or have a good reference that I can use?

Comment: How does this square with Whitehead's second lemma? https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Whitehead%27s_lemma_(Lie_algebra)

Comment: @AnginaSeng I don't have a proof of this, but presumably $\mathbb{C}$ isn't finite dimensional as a module over $L$, since the other conditions are that $L$ is a finite dimensional semisimple Lie algebra over a field of characteristic $0$, which are all clearly true.

Comment: If $L$ is a simple Lie algebra then $H^2(L,\mathbb{C})=0$. On the other hand, the $2$nd cohomology group of the *loop algebra* of $L$ may be non-zero. This is what is given in your reference.

Comment: So sorry guys! Major typo. Had to be the second cohomology group of the loop algebra indeed, since obviously the second cohomology of a fin dim simple one is zero.

Comment: You should replace $L \otimes \mathbb{C}$ in your question with either $L \otimes \mathbf{C}[t,t^{-1}]$ or $L \otimes \mathbf{C}((t))$. (Since $L \otimes \mathbf{C}=L$, and the algebraic definition of the loop algebra is either polynomial functions or formal functions from $\mathbf{C}^\times$ to $L$.)

Comment: Another typo...dammit. Fixed now.